# What is the cause of this error 'TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_HestonModelHelper'?

Tags: programming, quantlib, heston

I'm simulating the option prices every month using the Heston Model. The option contract expires at the of the month and the next option contract start the day after the previous contract expire. In order to simulate it, first,  I need to calibrate the parameters of Heston model. I construct the  Heston model helpers using the code below.

```
def helpers(strikes,spot,implied,param,calculation_date,expiration_date,risk_free_interest,dividend_rate):
    calendar = ql.India()
    theta,kappa,sigma,rho,v0  = list(param)
    
    flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, risk_free_rate, ql.Actual365Fixed()))
    dividend_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, dividend_rate, ql.Actual365Fixed()))    
    
    process = ql.HestonProcess(flat_ts, dividend_ts, 
                           ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot)), 
                           v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho)
    model = ql.HestonModel(process)
    engine = ql.AnalyticHestonEngine(model, 0.0001, 1000)

    for j, s in enumerate(strikes):
        t =  calendar.businessDaysBetween(calculation_date, expiration_date)
        p = ql.Period(t, ql.Days)
        sigma = implied[j]
        
        helper = ql.HestonModelHelper(p, calendar, spot , s , 
                                      ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(sigma)),
                                      flat_ts,
                                      dividend_ts)
        helper.setPricingEngine(engine)
        heston_helpers.append(helper)  
        grid_data.append((expiration_date,s))
    model = ql.HestonModel(process)
    engine = ql.AnalyticHestonEngine(model, 0.0001, 1000)
    return heston_helpers, grid_data, model
```

```
For the first option contract of 2014: 
strikes = [10000 10100 10200 10300 10400 ...]
spot = 10150.05
implied = [3.2958984375, 1.468658447265625, 0, 0, 0 ...]
param = (0.55, 15.5, 0.4, -0.5, 0.00659640970297048)
risk_free_interest =  0.0867
dividend_rate =  0.018000000000000002
calculation_date = December 27th, 2013 
expiration_date = January 30th, 2014
```

I ran the function with these inputs above but I ran into some kind of TypeError and I cant figure out why. I used the same function for my other simulations and it worked perfectly. Im just wondering why it doesnt work now. Can please someone help me?

```
<ipython-input-75-981b2d8597ce> in helpers(strikes, spot, implied, param, calculation_date, expiration_date,risk_interest_rate,dividend_rate)
     31                                       ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(sigma)),
     32                                       flat_ts,
---> 33                                       dividend_ts)
     34         helper.setPricingEngine(engine)
     35         heston_helpers.append(helper)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py in __init__(self, *args)
  10477 
  10478     def __init__(self, *args):
> 10479         _QuantLib.HestonModelHelper_swiginit(self, _QuantLib.new_HestonModelHelper(*args))
  10480     __swig_destroy__ = _QuantLib.delete_HestonModelHelper
  10481 

TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_HestonModelHelper'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    HestonModelHelper::HestonModelHelper(Period const &,Calendar const &,Real const,Real const,Handle< Quote > const &,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &,BlackCalibrationHelper::CalibrationErrorType)
    HestonModelHelper::HestonModelHelper(Period const &,Calendar const &,Real const,Real const,Handle< Quote > const &,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &,Handle< YieldTermStructure > const &)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be a wrong variable type in the inputs of the `HestonModelHelper` constructor.

There are a few errors in the code like `risk_free_rate` vs `risk_free_interest` as the variable name; and `heston_helpers` and `grid_data` not being defined inside the function but apart from that it should work if you give it the right type of inputs.

Here is a slight refactoring of your code but I suspect the problem was the way your inputs were defined.

```
import QuantLib as ql

def helpers(strikes, spot, implied, param, calculation_date, expiration_date, risk_free_interest, dividend_rate):
    heston_helpers= []
    calendar = ql.India()
    theta,kappa,sigma,rho,v0  = list(param)
    
    flat_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, risk_free_interest, ql.Actual365Fixed()))
    dividend_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.FlatForward(calculation_date, dividend_rate, ql.Actual365Fixed()))        
    process = ql.HestonProcess(flat_ts, dividend_ts, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot)), v0, kappa, theta, sigma, rho)
    model = ql.HestonModel(process)
    engine = ql.AnalyticHestonEngine(model, 0.0001, 1000)
    
    t =  calendar.businessDaysBetween(calculation_date, expiration_date)
    p = ql.Period(t, ql.Days)
    grid_data = [(expiration_date, strike) for strike in strikes]
    for strike, vol in zip(strikes, implied):
        helper = ql.HestonModelHelper(p, calendar, spot, strike, 
                                      ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(sigma)),
                                      flat_ts,
                                      dividend_ts)
        helper.setPricingEngine(engine)
        heston_helpers.append(helper)          
    return heston_helpers, grid_data, model


strikes = [10000, 10100, 10200, 10300, 10400]
implied = [3.2958984375, 1.468658447265625, 0, 0, 0]
spot = 10150.05
param = (0.55, 15.5, 0.4, -0.5, 0.00659640970297048)
calculation_date = ql.Date(27, 12, 2013)
expiration_date = ql.Date(30, 1, 2014)
risk_free_interest =  0.0867
dividend_rate =  0.018
helpers(strikes, spot, implied, param, calculation_date, expiration_date, risk_free_interest, dividend_rate)
```

You can check this [link](https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/thelpers.html#hestonmodelhelper) for some examples.